# How to check mysql fetched rows in while loop are same

Tags: php, mysql

how to check resulted row values from while loop are same,I need to update when status is completed from all results...

```
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM fy_working_staf_cstm WHERE task_id_c='".$t_id."'");
        while($row = $db->fetchRow($result)){
          ++$tas;
            $staff_id=$row['id_c'];
            $result1 = $db->query("SELECT `status` FROM `fy_working_staf` WHERE id='".$staff_id."' AND `status`='Completed'");
            $staf = $db->fetchByAssoc($result1);
            $status = $staf['status'];
            if($stat=='Completed')
             {
                ++$tas1;
                //$comple_staus='Closed_Closed';
             }
        }
        if(($tas == $tas1) && ($tas1 !=0) )
        {
            $q = $db->query("UPDATE `tasks` SET `status`='Completed' WHERE id='".$t_id."' ");
            $st = $db->fetchByAssoc($q);    
        }
```

Comment: `$t_id` what's the value for that? When in doubt, var dump and check for errors

Comment: Do you mean `if($status=='Completed')` because I see no variable called `$stat`

Comment: OMG how can i do this tomyself thanks RiggsFolly  i have been using this condition in to situations i copied but did look at the variable now its working ... thanks lot i was scratching my head for so long . is there any other better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead i can use break condition in this  as :

```
  while($row = $db->fetchRow($result)){
        $staff_id=$row['id_c'];
        $result1 = $db->query("SELECT `status` FROM `fy_working_staf` WHERE id='".$staff_id."' AND `status`='Completed'");
        $staf = $db->fetchByAssoc($result1);
        $status = $staf['status'];
        if($stat!='Completed')
         {
            $comple_staus='Closed_Closed';
            break;// will exit the loop when the row is not same

         }
    }
```